# 502 gateway error while deploying React v16.7 application in Google GCP app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

hi I recently upgraded my React App from React v15.x to React v16.7.0 using create-react-application 
I did couple of changes as below

1. After upgrading my app start failing because my previous app setup has both client and server part in same app. hence I compiled client part separately using 
   create-react-application project
2. then I merged my server part package.json with app created using create-react-application and brought my server part into same project
3. I setup proxy for my server as suggested in [facebook help page](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

everything working fine in local machine, however when I tried deploying to google GCP app engine, got error 'invalid host header' , then I setup HOST: 'localhost' in app.yml file after that I am getting 502 Gateway error

any idea what needs to be done ?

My observations : create-react-application will run app at 3000 port, but for google gcp app should be running on 8080 port, hence I setup PORT=8080 in package.json as follows

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Even with port 8080 I am still facing 502 gateway

Comment: Is it just "invalid host header"? Please provide full error message.

Comment: @SLCH000 as i mentioned in my question, I solved 'invalid host header' by putting host='localhost' in yml file. but now am facing 502 gateway error.

Answer (score 2):

Add `HOST=your-appengine-domain` to env file

Comment: I got below error 
Could not find an open port at <host_name>.
Network error message: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available <ip_address>

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! <app_name> start: `node src/server/app.js & node src/server/apiServer.js & react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the <appname> start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/app-debug.log